# Singleton объект не возвращает значение поля, которое он создал при инициализации

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, dependency-injection

Решил написать бота на `C# Telegram.Bot`. Я видел много туториалов, в котором тяжело было расширять бота. Я начал его писать как сервис, с **Dependency Injection**. Чтобы пользоваться одним объектом `ITelegramBotClient`(этот объект позволяет боту: написать сообщение, удалить участника из группы, то есть использовать его API). В `program.cs` добавил этот объект как Singleton. Но начали происходить ошибки. Во время дебага, увидел, что мой объект `TelegramBot`(который должен возращать один объект `ITelegramBotClient`) присваивает его **readonly** полю. Но когда я извне пытаюсь добраться до этого поля через свойство или метод, мне возращает `null`. Помогите пожалуйста:

`Program.cs`:

```cs
namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddSingleton<TelegramBot>(); // Здесь я добавил свой объект как синглтон
                    services.AddSingleton<IUpdateHandler, UpdateHandler>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ICommandExecutor, CommandExecutor>();
                    services.AddSingleton<BaseCommand, StartCommand>();
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

`TelegramBot.cs`:

```cs
namespace WorkerService1.Services
{
    public class TelegramBot
    {
        private readonly ITelegramBotClient _bot;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public TelegramBot(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;

            var token = _config.GetValue<string>("BotToken") ?? throw new Exception("There's no \"BotToken\" parameter in appsetting.json");
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("165.225.38.29", 10605),
                UseProxy = true
            };
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            var _bot = new TelegramBotClient(token, httpClient); // присваивает значение не null.
        }

        public ITelegramBotClient GetBot()
        {
            return _bot; // Однако тут возращает null
        }
    }
}
```

`Worker.cs`(этот класс отвечает за инициализацию проекта):

```cs
namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IUpdateHandler _updateHandler;
        private readonly TelegramBot _bot;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration config, IUpdateHandler updateHandler, TelegramBot bot)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
            _updateHandler = updateHandler;
            _bot = bot;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var bot = _bot.GetBot() ?? throw new Exception("TelegramBot.GetBot() has returned null value"); // Здесь всегда выбрасывает исключение.
            var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
            {
                Limit = 1
            };

            bot.StartReceiving(
                updateHandler: _updateHandler,
                receiverOptions: receiverOptions,
                cancellationToken: stoppingToken
            );

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

> Вот гит, кому нужен
>
> > https://github.com/HikashiMlbb/FannyHikashiBotTelegram/tree/master/WorkerService1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда Вы пишите:

```
var _bot = new TelegramBotClient(token, httpClient);
```

то вы работаете не с полем класса, а с локальной переменной метода.
Поэтому рабочим вариантом будет:

```
_bot = new TelegramBotClient(token, httpClient);
```

С полями нужно работать ровно так как у Вас написано в конструкторе `Worker` а тут возможно вы машинально написали.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что увидели опечатку. Я столько времени потратил на то, чтобы понять, почему поле `_bot` всё время имеет значение `null`, а оказалось, на это повлияло одно ключевое слово) Благодарю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, и будьте внимательны)